# Renaming folders from a list

Tags: powershell

I have a text file list of 56 folders that includes the full paths to a set of folders. I need to rename the folder at the end of the path.
Example:

```
Original: \this folder\needs to\move  
New: \this folder\needs to\move.moved
```

I am totally new at powershell and trying to learn. I thought this might be a good way to start.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Get the content of the list
# in this case, a text file with no heading, and one path per line
$listContent = Get-Content $ENV:USERPROFILE\Desktop\list.txt


# Loop over each child folder and rename it

foreach($line in $listContent)
{
    # check if the current path is valid

    $pathTest = Test-Path -Path $line

    if($pathTest -eq $True)
    {
        Write-Output "`nOld path: $($line)"
        $newName = $line + ".moved"

        Write-Output "New name: $newName"

        try 
        {
            # on success, write out message
            Rename-Item -Path $line -NewName $newName -Force

            # split the string from the file and get the data after the last \ for readability
            Write-Output "`nSuccessfully changed directory name $($line.split('\')[-1]) to $newName"
        }
        catch 
        {
            # on error, throw first error in the Error array
            throw $Error[0]
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "$($line) is not a valid path"
    }

}

Write-Output "`nEnd of script!"
```